# Zend insert user and set value to max()+1

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

My code:

```
public function insertMember($member) 
{   
    $maxOrderNumber = $this->select()
        ->from($this, array(new Zend_Db_Expr('max(order_number)')));

    $id = $this->insert($member, $maxOrderNumber);
    return $id;
}
```

I want to insert member to last position in members table and order_number entity. Tried with `$maxOrderNumber` but i keep getting 0 value in database.

Im using MySql. Also i have user_id with (AI) Autoincrement so i'm forced to function this way.

Comment: It's been a while since I used ZF1, but `$this->select()` returns a query object - you will need to execute that query to get your integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function insertMember($member) 
{   
    $maxOrderNumber = $this->select()
        ->from($this, array(new Zend_Db_Expr('max(order_number)')));
    $stmt = $maxOrderNumber ->query();
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $id = $this->insert($member, $result ['order_number']);
    return $id;
}
```

soemthing like that...